How to install 4 wire plug on old Maytag dryer with two ground wires near connectors?
Attempting to ground older Maytag Legacy Series dryer properly with 14-30 receptacle and 4 prong plug. Can’t find a sticker with model info anywhere on the dryer. (Looked inside and out.) Two ground wires attached to frame near hot/neutral connectors. One feeds into the neutral connector. The other follows the device’s other wires up to the top. I believe I need to pair the ground from the neutral connector with the plug neutral and replace it with the plug ground at the frame. Can anybody confirm this?



Or this? Replacing dryer cord (3 to 4 prong), where to connect existing ground?

Or this? Converting dryer from 3 to 4 prong cord but it doesn't have a grounding screw / wire
